# Scala reflection java.rmi dependency, can it work on Android?

Tags: android, scala, reflection, dependencies, rmi

I would like to use the Scala (2.11) reflection package's runtime mirror in a Scala application compiled for android which is being build using [Scala on android](http://scala-android.org/).

I was able to fiddle with ProGuard options in order to make it include the required Scala classes. However when I try to get a mirror instance:

```
universe.runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
```

(Indeed it fails during the lazy computation of `universe`)

The application crashes in run time:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/rmi/Remote;
at     scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RemoteInterfaceClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:370)
at     scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RemoteInterfaceClass(D    efinitions.scala:370)
at     scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverseForce$class.force(JavaUniverseForce.scal    a:255)
at     scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.force(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
at     scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.init(JavaUniverse.scala:147)
at     scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.<init>(JavaUniverse.scala:78)
at     scala.reflect.runtime.package$.universe$lzycompute(package.scala:17)
at     scala.reflect.runtime.package$.universe(package.scala:17)
```

This crash is for me as expected as it isn't:

**It is expected** as `java.rmi` is not part of the Android API and I should expect any code trying to load its classes to crash.

**It is unexpected** as I didn't know that Scala's reflect package used `java.rmi`

I have traced the code to were `rmi` is required, that is to `JavaUniverse` (a trait mixed in `JavaUniverse` class) `force` method:

```
...
definitions.RemoteInterfaceClass
...
```

Which leads to `DefinitionsClass`:

```
lazy val RemoteInterfaceClass  = requiredClass[java.rmi.Remote]
```

**Am I wrong to think that this is a no-go for Scala reflection in Android?**
If I am, what could be a workaround to this problem?

Comment: Have you found a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize [your solution](https://gitter.im/scala-android/sbt-android/archives/2017/03/07) and a [related solution](https://github.com/scala/pickling/issues/140), it is sufficient to add two files, and modify `build.sbt` to include:

```
dexAdditionalParams in Android += "--core-library"
```

Add `java/rmi/Remote.java` to your project with the content:

```
package java.rmi;
public interface Remote {}
```

Add `java/rmi/RemoteException.java` to your project with the content:

```
package java.rmi;
public interface RemoteException {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the summary, I didn't have the change to answer it by myself yet. 

I would add that I had to add a couple of additional parameters to the DEX generator:

`dexMaxHeap in Android :="4096M"`
`dexMulti in Android := true`

Here https://github.com/pfcoperez/android_scalarpel/blob/master/build.sbt you can find the project were it's been applied, it's rather abandoned now but I hope I can continue with it soon.

Comment: Additionally, you should keep in mind (I would add a warning in the answer) that this is a "dirty" hack and that the `sbt-android` maintainer warns against using Java reflection in this context.

Comment: I'll second the dirtiness of this, it feels wrong.  Sometimes there's just no choice, though.  E.g., in my case I'm relying on a third party library that makes extensive use of reflection.